# Load External Swf From Link [As3]

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to call a swf from a link in as3. I searched on internet and i used this code

```
var my_Loader:Loader = new Loader();
var my_url:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://gurselgunacar.web44.net/flash/yalitimhesabi.swf");
my_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);
my_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
my_Loader.load(my_url);
function finishLoading(loadEvent:Event) {
addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}
function errorHandler(errorEvent:Event):void {
trace("file missing");
}
```

as3 call link but i cant do anything in swf. In output flash give security error. And i tried crossdomain.xml thing and it didnt work :S

Comment: I think you cannot request files from internet like this when testing locally in flash environment. try uploading your swf file to your webhost.

Comment: but i need it in .exe format :S

Answer (score 2):

The file http://gurselgunacar.web44.net/crossdomain.xml does not exists. You should create one.

The Loader will always look for a crossdomain.xml file at the target server.

Comment: ı upload but still same. <?xml version="1.0"?>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="&quot;*&quot;"/>
</cross-domain-policy>

Answer (score 0):

Humm. Try to add these Security things:

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://gurselgunacar.web44.net/crossdomain.xml");
```

And use this in the URLRequest:

```
var my_url:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://gurselgunacar.web44.net/flash/yalitimhesabi.swf?" + new Date().getTime()); //this will avoid caching old swf.
```

I tested on a EXE projector and it seems to work.

Comment: security problem solved :) but now in output : TypeError: Error #1009: Boş nesne başvuru özelliğine veya yöntemine erişilemiyor.
 at asdfg_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
also i cant do anyting in swf.